# Giving 2 subplots different subtitles

Tags: python, seaborn

so I have been plotting two different charts and now would like to add different subtitles. Unfortunately my code is not running (its from the bottom the 2nd and 3rd row). I hope somebody can help me and thank you in advance.

```
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(12,5))
sns.countplot(x='month',hue='year', data=continent_0[continent_0["is_booking"] == 1], ax=ax1)
sns.pointplot(x='month',y='is_booking',hue='year', ci=None, data=continent_0, ax=ax2)
ax1.set(xlabel = 'Month', ylabel = 'Bookings')
ax2.set(xlabel = 'Month', ylabel = 'Bookings')

ax1.fig.suptitle('Absoulute Number of Bookings', y=1.03)
ax2.fig.suptitle('Conversion Rate', y=1.03)

plt.subplots_adjust(wspace = 0.2)
```

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'fig'

Comment: It's `ax1.set_title()`, `ax2.set_title()`